# If for $a,b,x \in \mathbb{N}$ if we have $a \mid x, b \mid x$ prove that $\operatorname{lcm} (a,b) \leq x$

Tags: solution-verification

> If for $a,b,x \in \mathbb{N}$ if we have $$a \mid x, b \mid x$$ prove that $\operatorname{lcm} (a,b) \leq x$

---

My solution: maximum value of $a,b$ is when they are both $x$, in which case their lcm is also $x$, but if any of them are less than $x$ then their lcm can't get bigger, hence their lcm is always less than $x$. Is this correct?

Comment: How are you defining the LCM?

Comment: @lulu lcm is the least common multiple.

Comment: Yes, and what is your definition of that?  My point is that I can't understand your question.  It seems to me to be a literal restatement of the definition.  So, perhaps you are using an exotic definition?

Comment: @math_learner, think calmly. First understand what l.c.m.(a,b) is. This is not even a question.

Comment: @lulu The least common multiple (LCM) of two numbers is the lowest possible number that can be divisible by both numbers. Now following this definition, is my solution correct?

Comment: I don't understand.  $x$ is a common multiple.  the LCM is the least common multiple, so by definition the LCM is $≤x$.  What is there to prove?  It's like "Bob is the shortest person in the room. Dave is also in the room, prove that Bob is no taller than Dave."

Answer (score 0):

> maximum value of $a,b$ is when they are both $x$

This doesn't make sense, because your $a,b, x$ are some fixed integers. If let $c=$max$(a,b)$, then $c$ is also a fixed number, so it is either $c< x, c=x$ or $c> x$. You cannot treat them as to first fix $x$ and then let $a, b$ vary and compare with your previously fixed $x$.

The least common multiple is $L=lcm(a, b)=a_1gb_1$, where $a=ga_1, b=gb_1,$ and $\gcd(a_1, b_1)=1$.

If $a|x$, then we have $x=ka, k\in\mathbb{N}^+$, then it gives $x=kga_1.$ If  $b|x$, then we have $gb_1|kga_1\Rightarrow b_1|ka_1$, since $\gcd(a_1, b_1)=1$, it means $b_1|k$, so we have $k=tb_1, t\in \mathbb{N}^+$,

$$x=kga_1=tb_1ga_1=tL\Rightarrow x\ge L$$